# Limit Choices of Foreign Keys in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model Commodity:

```
class Commodity(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, related_name='commodity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_old = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    price_new = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I tried to use `limit_choices_to` and it didn't work.
I have a Serializer:

```
class CommoditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = CommodityImageSerializer(many=False)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        queryset = Commodity.objects.filter(shop__company__user=user)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ('id', 'shop', 'brand', 'price_old', 'price_new')
```

This get_queryset also dont help me.
Finally I have a regular CreateAPIView, and this method also dont help me.
How can I limit usage of foreign keys? I need to let create commodities to my user only within user's Shops. THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can simply implement [`validate_shop`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) method for this:

```
class CommoditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = CommodityImageSerializer(many=False)

    def validate_shop(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if value.company.user == user:
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid shop!')

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ('id', 'shop', 'brand', 'price_old', 'price_new')
```

Comment: Am I right considering this a good practice to leave all final validation to frontend? (I mean all that shops that user can't see, but can use)

Comment: @D.Make no, leave validation on the frontend side is not a good practice at all. In you case you should filter shops on backend before return it to the frontend.

Comment: @newerwalkaloner I'm about your answer. Serializer Validation let fronend get the list of all shops and don't let choose not user's shop. Is it ok, that backend show the full list of shops, even that, which user can't use?

Comment: @D.Make `CommoditySerializer` doesn't return shop objects at all. I don't know in which view you send shops to the frontend, but filtering should be performed there.

Comment: I was about HTML form that shows me choices. As I understand now It is made just for tests and should be turned off after development. Of cause I have brand filtering. Thanks!